# Simple progress indication in console

Tags: haskell, progress

What is the easiest way to indicate the work progress in console? Outputting the percentage will be enough, progress bar is not necessary.

Using just `print` will produce lot's of lines, I want just a single changing string in a terminal.

Comment: also, you may just use some form of `echo` which doesn't prints line break, thus there was a `back one symbol erase` control character, so you can make a rotator animation (made from -/|\)

Comment: My Haskell is kind of rusty to say the least, but if I remember correctly, using putStr with a \r at the end will do a carriage return without a line feed which should let you overwrite the line you're on.

Comment: @kagali-san, Joachim Isaksson, thanks for the cool suggestions: `sequence_ . intersperse (threadDelay 100000) . map (putStr . (: "\r")) $ cycle "-\\|/"`.

Comment: @Rotsor I found that interspersing `threadDelay` causes the output to be swallowed. To fix this I just flush `stdout` by replace `(threadDelay 100000)` with `(hFlush stdout >> threadDelay 100000)`

Answer (score 23):

The simplest way would be to do what wget and other programs do: printing out a carriage return and an ANSI erase-line code before the progress information, thus returning the cursor to the start of the line and replacing the existing text. For example:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import System.IO
import Text.Printf

putProgress :: String -> IO ()
putProgress s = hPutStr stderr $ "\r\ESC[K" ++ s

drawProgressBar :: Int -> Rational -> String
drawProgressBar width progress =
  "[" ++ replicate bars '=' ++ replicate spaces ' ' ++ "]"
  where bars = round (progress * fromIntegral width)
        spaces = width - bars

drawPercentage :: Rational -> String
drawPercentage progress = printf "%3d%%" (truncate (progress * 100) :: Int)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  forM_ [0..10] $ \i -> do
    let progress = fromIntegral i / 10
    putProgress $ drawProgressBar 40 progress ++ " " ++ drawPercentage progress
    threadDelay 250000
  putProgress "All done."
  hPutChar stderr '\n'
```

The key thing here is to *not* print a newline, so that you can return to the start of the line on the next progress update.

Of course, you could just print out the percentage here and drop the bar, but a bar is cooler :)

Comment: It might be a good idea to print to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. You get automatic flushing, and it's possible to use this program in a pipe without the progress bar screwing up.

Comment: @dflemstr: Good point! I've updated the code with a simpler solution that prints to stderr.

Answer (score 3):

If I want something really quick and dirty, what I tend to do is just print a sequence of dots. Every time there's been "a bit more" progress I just write another dot (with no newline). I tune the measure of "a bit of progress" so that the dots come on about the time scale of a dot per second. Not very sophisticated, but it shows the program is doing something.

If you actually have some sort of measure of how much total "progress" there will be (I often don't, but this is suggested by your mention of percentages), then you can just declare the whole program to be X dots, and print one every time you make 1/X progress.